# Missing Audio despite wave form being present

Tags: audio, logic-pro, playback

After recording audio via a mic, some of the audio won't play in sections, despite the audio being visible. If the audio wave form was missing in parts I'd assume its a faulty mic or cable, but the wave form is visible right through the recording. Using a Universal Audio 8xP interface with Logic Pro X and all other audio is working. Any ideas

Answer (score 1):

try importing the audio into another DAW or audio player and do some elimination testing.